# Low Quality Post Recommend deletion more options

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

When reviewing low quality posts, the *Recommend Deletion* option has bunch of optional comments, like "Link-only answer" or so.. But sometimes none of the provided options reflect the real case.
It may be good to provide a way to leave a custom message, like we have in flags.

For example, I saw couple of answers which were just one or two lines of code, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116808/putting-php-variables-into-soap-request-array/19119763#19119763).

When flagging, we have the **other** option which allows to flag post for reason not covered by common options. I just thought here it may be useful too, for the rare cases which happen from time to time.

Comment: Do you have some examples?  What other kinds of posts do you think should be deleted?

Comment: Why would you want to recommend deletion of that answer just because it's a few lines of code? That's not a good reason for it to be deleted...

Comment: @animuson I've found the queue delete reasons to be somewhat different from the flag reasons, most importantly that "link only answer" seems to be a delete reason whereas I wouldn't flag a link only answer for deletion

Comment: Would not "other" in flags be equivalent to "no comment" in recommend deletion

Comment: @RichardTingle The "other" option allows to type some text, not just select "other". The delete reason is posted as a comment to the answer and the author can react and improve thus saving the post from deletion.

Comment: @RichardTingle But what does that have to do with the example here? At least the user provided an *answer* here on the site. There's absolutely no reason whatsoever why that answer should be deleted.

Comment: @animuson Only mild relevance, my point was that what the review queue *is* is slightly unclear at this point, leading to this request for more reasons for things to "not look good". Other reasons that shouldn't lead to deletion are already in there

Comment: @ShimonRachlenko You can always make a manual comment if you want to, especially as in that case you are presumably commenting but not recommending deletion

Comment: I posted this question when the adding comments was disabled from review tasks. Now it is enabled, thus solving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of the "Low Quality Posts" review.

Specifically, "Recommend Deletion" should not be used for answers that are salvageable through editing.  Posts that are just 1 or 2 lines of code are not necessarily "delete worthy" unless that have other serious problems that makes them impossible to fix.

If you encounter a poor quality post, such as the one you described, you should add your own comment (outside of review), but unless the post needs to be deleted, you should hit "Looks Good".

The existing options help narrow down exactly what is wrong to leave a "helpful" comment if/when the post is deleted.

The confusion could be over the text of the button.  "Looks Goods" is supposed to mean that the post does not need to be deleted and it not a Spam/Thank you/Comment post.  "No Action Needed" or "Does not need Deleted" (which is probably too long) are better ways to describe the "positive" action from this queue.

Comment: This I think is a major problem with that queue, I usually either skip or recommend deletion because they certainly do not "look good"

Comment: @RichardTingle Maybe the wording on the "Looks Good" button needs changed, but the queue is basically similar to the "Very Low Quality" flag.  It is not for bad posts.  It is for unsalvagable posts that need to be deleted right away.

Comment: @RichardTingle I don't know why they chose Looks Good for this queue and No Action Needed for the others, but No Action Needed still fits better for this queue.